# Domain Reputation - sending Emails through AWS SES

Tags: email, email-server, amazon-ses

I send emails through AWS SES to increase the chances of my emails being delivered to users. It's been working quite well so far.

However, as I send emails through AWS SES, is the Reputation of my Domain improving overtime?

If one day I decide to leave AWS SES and send emails from my own SMTP server (with the same quality of emails), will I keep the Domain Reputation gained while I was sending through AWS SES, or would I be "stuck" with continuing to use AWS SES to keep the reputation gained?

Comment: Further reading for those finding this on search: https://www.mailgun.com/blog/deliverability/domain-ip-reputation-gmail-care-more-about/ and https://postmarkapp.com/blog/the-importance-of-domain-reputation

Comment: https://postmarkapp.com/blog/take-your-reputation-with-you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your domain reputation will prevails,
 but that's not enough to send, like sending in AWS SES. 
AWS are warming up their IP for you. In your case, You need warm up your own IP of your email server slowly even though you had a warmed up domain